# How to configure kotlin dsl to make springboot multiple modules packaged as executable jar files

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

How to configure kotlin dsl to make springboot multiple modules packaged as executable jar files.

I just started using kotlin dsl and looked up a lot of information without success.

I've tried many ways to build files that don't contain my own code.

Here is some of the code

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("application")
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.20"
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.5.20"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.20"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "5.1.0"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

tasks.getByName<KotlinCompile>("compileKotlin") {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
val fatJar = task("fatJar", type = Jar::class) {
    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.MainApplicationKt"
    }
    from(configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().map({ if (it.isDirectory) it else zipTree(it) }))
    // with(jar.get() as CopySpec)
    with(tasks.jar.get() as CopySpec)
}

tasks {
    "build" {
        dependsOn(fatJar)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the Spring plugin has added the ability to compose the output fat JAR. You do not need to write the fatJar task yourself.

Comment: Yes, but I found an exception when I added project in the sub project tag.